# How can I use variable of a function in another function defined inside it's body?

Tags: javascript, function, variables, scope

Here is my code:

```
        function checkUsername(){
            var checkForm;

            if (window.XMLHttpRequest) {
                // code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
                xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
            } else {
                // code for IE6, IE5
                xmlhttp = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
            }

            xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function() {
                if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
                    if(this.responseText == 'Username Available'){
                        checkForm = true;   
                        alert(checkForm);
                    }
                    else{
                        checkForm = false;
                    }
                    errorElement.innerHTML = this.responseText;
                }
            }
            xmlhttp.open("GET","unamechecker.php?str=" + str);
            xmlhttp.send();
            alert(checkForm);
            return checkForm;
        }
```

First alert() will output **true** no doubt. But second alert() will output **undefined** as the value of `checkForm` assigned **true** is in another function (defined inside the parent function) and do not have any value in it's function. I want to use the `checkForm` variable value in parent function as changed by sub-function. How can I acheive this?

**Don't suggest to make `checkForm` global variable, as I have many methods on the same page have variable name `checkForm`.**

Comment: you have a sync/async issue, not a scope issue. checkUsername() will return before the HTTP request returns and sets your flag. consider using a promise to solve your sync issue.

Comment: SO the variable changed in the inner function will maintain its value outside the inner function?

Comment: yes, through the closure. but you have a timing issue. check the link provided at the top of your question, there is a ton of great info in there.